Relationship between differential lambda calculus and automatic differentiation
I'm familiar with both, especially the dual numbers form of automatic differentiation. I'm wondering if someone could clarify the relationship between the two -- as I understand it, they coincide on first-order terms (since the first order fragment of differential lambda calculus is modelled by differential categories). That said, I'm struggling to see this directly: how is it that linear substitution relates to taking symbolic derivatives of functions between reals? Further, the two approaches seem to diverge on higher order terms, with dual numbers automatic differentiation simply lifting the derivative to higher types in the "obvious" functorial way, but with differential lambda calculus doing something more involved.
